# 'Ballparking' Number of DB Records to Save Cpu Cycles

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I noticed Gmail started to 'ballpark' the number of results for searches and wondered if this was simply an aesthetic change or if it actually saved on cpu cycles.

When performing a search in Gmail it says something along the lines of

> Viewing 10 results of (hundreds, thousands, etc)

Are there SQL techniques for this? Are there performance benefits?

Anything to point me in a direction to learn more would be helpful.

Comment: I wonder if they are looking at the size of the table and dividing by expected row size instead of doing a count. This may be a faster way of get a quick and dirty answer.

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure google search is not using mysql.  But you can ball park a table's size in mysql by doing

```
show table status like 'table_name';
```